# How do I skip the margin top on this js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to figure this out; how do I get the .float-div not to margin from the top while scrolling down? I would like it to be fixed on the top of the window while scrolling. If you take away the .top-entry it will work fine. But how can I fix it without deleting the .top-entry?

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Kjc6k/2/

```
var $scrollingDiv = $(".float-div");

$(window).scroll(function(){      
var y = $(this).scrollTop(),
$postEntry = $('.post-entry'),
maxY = $postEntry.offset().top + $postEntry.height(),
scrollHeight = $scrollingDiv.height();
if(y< maxY-scrollHeight ){
$scrollingDiv
.stop()
.animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"}, "slow" );        
}    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my new answer, this is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Kjc6k/48/
hope this is what you are looking for :)

```
var $scrollingDiv = $(".float-div");


$(window).scroll(function(){  


var y = $(this).scrollTop(),
    $topEntry = $('.top-entry').height();
if( y > $topEntry){
    $scrollingDiv
    .stop()
    .animate({"margin-top": y + "px"}, "slow" );        
} 
else 
    $scrollingDiv
    .stop()
    .animate({"margin-top": "80px"}, "slow" ); 
});
```

Comment: That works great, but now the problem is that the .float-div scrolls over the .sep-entry. I would like it to stop exactly on top of the .sep-entry. Because if the .float-div has a height of example 600px, then you  can scroll down forever! Try to set a height of 300px on the .float-div and scroll down. Then you understand what I mean!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: so you want that .float-div scroll only in .post-entry?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `top:0` to float-div class will easily fix this.

```
.float-div {
position: absolute;
background: red;
top: 0;
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7KSTs/

Comment: @moe Thanks for the replay Moe! The first solution you hade make the .float-div go to the top, but I would like it to remain under the "top-entry". The last solution you have is great, but I would like it to still have the animation on the scroll. Thanks!

Comment: @David I dont really understand what is the problem here. Can you explain better?

Comment: The problem is that the .float-div has a margin-top when you scroll down on the page. I would like it to be fixed on the top of the window when you have scrolled under/passed the .top-entry. If you do not get me, just say it again and I will try to explain :)

Comment: Now its clear. But answer is very easy, you just calculate height of the top-entry and compare it to current scroll position, if scroll position is more than set with jquery css> top:0